# Recent religious landscape study (post 2020)

Tags: resource-request, demographics

I'm looking for a report that shows religious affiliation change in the past 5 years.

The kind of report I'm looking for should have details similar to the [2014 Pew Religious Landscape Study](https://www.pewresearch.org/religion/2015/05/12/americas-changing-religious-landscape/) that at least has [net gains and losses by tradition](https://www.pewresearch.org/religion/2015/05/12/chapter-2-religious-switching-and-intermarriage/) like Catholicism, Evangelical, mainline Protestants, other religions, nones, etc.  The scope of the report can be worldwide, by continent, or specific to a country.

Here's the change from 2007 to 2014 for USA only:

[image: Religious Switching by Tradition]

Comment: Am I reading this metric correctly in that it's saying only Evangelical and Other have significant % growth?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Yes.  But this is 8-15 year old statistics.

Comment: I like how the Mainline Protestant group is about half the Evangelical Protestant group. At what point does a thread of Protestantism stop being 'mainline'?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather I believe it’s non-denominational vs denominational, but I could be wrong

Comment: @OneGodtheFather [Mainline Protestant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainline_Protestant) means historic denomination (the "Seven Sisters" plus smaller ones like Mennonite), in contrast with Evangelical (1800s), Pentecostal/Charismatic (1900s), and other non-denominational.  They tend to be more liberal in their theology.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Ya, but they're not really the *main* line anymore, are they?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather If you mean they will soon be not majority anymore, I think you're right.  The [history of the terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainline_Protestant#Terminology) is interesting.  I didn't know this, also didn't know that it's a recent (100 year) US-centric terminology.  I think a better term for them now should be historic Protestant denominations.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Interesting! Thanks for that link.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather My response in [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135611/being-a-christian-vs-christianity).